# How enable a disabled button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple search input field with button in my page. The search button is disabled and I activate it when the user insert more then 4 chars in the input field. I successfully enable the button but when I click on it nothing happens.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">

          <button type="button" id="start-search" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>                                                
     </span>
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input-code" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Search registration">

</div>
```

The Javascript jQuery code that works so far: I succesfully enabled the button when the user insert more then 4 chars in the input field.

```
$("#input-code").keyup(function() {
        var char = $(this).val();
        var charLength = $(this).val().length;

        var regex = new function() {
            this.noPrefix = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
            this.foreignPrefix = /^[^iI]-/;
        }
        var code = char.toUpperCase(char);

        if (regex.withPrefix.test(char) || regex.noPrefix.test(char))
        {

            if (regex.noPrefix.test(char))
            {
                code = 'I-' + code;     
            }

            $(this).attr("placeholder", code).val("").blur();

        }
        else
        {
            if(charLength > 4 ){
                $( "#start-search" ).prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
```

The code that doesn't work. Nothin happens when I click the button.

```
$('#start-search').click(function(){
        if (this.id == 'start-search') {
            alert('Submit 1 clicked');
        };
        var code = $('#input-code').val();
        code = code.toUpperCase(code);
        console.log("Looking for " + code + " registration");
        $('#input-code').attr("placeholder", code).val("").blur();
        searchData(code);
    });
```

I have added the console.log and alert code just for debug.
If I remove the disabled attribute the button works fine...what am I missing?

Just one more question: how can I pass a data structure object to the searchData function? Right now I just pass a variable.
Thanks a lot for any help and hint.

When the user insert more then 4 chars in the input field the button get activated; clicking on it I should call the searchData function to retrieve and display other info.

Comment: What does this condition do `regex.withPrefix.test(char) || regex.noPrefix.test(char)` ? I suppose that this condition is always true so the `else` will never work and the `disabled` attribute to button will never be false

Comment: `regex.withPrefix` is never defined. This will give a js error because you call `test()` on an a undefined property. Other then that your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm very sorry since the code above it's not correct...I mean that regex.withPrefix is defined...I copied a wrong code over there. As I wrote I can activate the button...after a user type more then 4 chars the button become clickable...but when I click on it nothing happens...I shoudl see an alert...a console log message...and I should call the searchData() function...nothing is executed.